# What does the output of Imagemagicks identify mean?

Tags: imagemagick

Can someone please explain me the following output of imagemagicks identify?

`image.gif GIF 345x49 345x49+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 1.79KB 0.000u 0:00.000`
I know the follwing:

I know that GIF is the file extension, 345 is the width, 49 is height, 8-bit is the [color depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth). 1.79KB is the file size.

But what does `PseudoClass`, `256c` and `0.000u 0:00.000` mean?

If I verbose the output, I get even more results I don't understand:

- `Type: Bilevel`
- `Base type: Bilevel`
- `Depth: 8/1-bit`
- `signature:`
- `Artifacts:    verbose: true`
- `Tainted: False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mostly guessing and copying from [ImageMagick "Basics"](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/)**:

- `PseudoClass 256c` – image uses a color map (color palette) containing at most 256 colors; standard for GIF images. (If the image specifies color values directly, it would be `DirectClass`.)
- `Type: Bilevel` apparently means the image is a two-color monochrome. (`Palette` means the entire palette is used; `TrueColor` for 24-bit RGB and such; `...Matte` suffix means an additional transparency value is used)
- `Depth: 8/1-bit` – not entirely sure; `8-bit` means 8 bits per value, which is standard for GIFs. The one bit could be the GIF transparency.

  (For "Palette" images, each pixel has one value, the color index in palette; for "TrueColor", each pixel usually has 3-4 values: R/G/B and optional transparency)
- The `signature` property is a hash of the image.

Some properties are not about the file contents but about the in-memory image objects used by ImageMagick:

- The `verbose` artifact means ImageMagick will output verbose information about the image; you added it by using `-verbose`.
- `Tainted` is true if the image has been modified since loading.

Comment: Just to add one thing that's missing from this answer, and which I had to ask on the Imagemagic forum to find out (http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=27326&p=121062)... `0.000u` is "User Time" and `0:00.000` is the "Total Elapsed Time" that it takes for identify to check the image.